# How to override the SMTP error message on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, smtp

Any idea about how override this error message?

```
An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution was to catch the exception and return the desired message.

```
begin
    ...
rescue ArgumentError => error
    render json: { object: { errors: ["New message"] } }, status: 422
end
```